# How to declare a variable within if/switch statements that would become global?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

**I am trying to use multiple custom UITableViewCells without having to duplicate all the code in cellForRowAt method for each option**

I am creating a real-time chat app for learning purposes that differentiates the cell class based on weather the message sender is the user or not. I know how to give cellForRowAt the relevant ReusableCell either with if-else or switch statement, but the problem is:

1. The 200 lines of code that deals with the cell properties does not
   have access to the cell variable unless I define it **outside** these
   switch/if statements.
2. When I do define it in the header of the function it requires a **predefined type**
3. If I pick either type as default and declare it I get an error of them being **not compatible**, when in fact they are 100% identical from the code point of view (only the design differs).
4. If I declare it a generic UITableViewCell type then the type lacks all my custom properties.
5. If I try to create a common base class I am unable to link up my
   @IBOutlets and @IBActions, which are the bulk of the commonalities.
   If I try to build a protocol, the protocol does not support anything
   @IB.

This problem could be solved if I could declare the cell variable within if/switch statement and make it visible for the rest of my code without having to nest it inside the if/switch. Is there any way to do that?

PS. I know I could overcome this problem by duplicating the 200 lines of code for every variation of custom tableview cell, but my gut tells me that there has to be more clever way to do this.

Here's a code snippet to illustrate the problem:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    // Get the info about the message from an array
    let message = messageArray[indexPath.row]

    // Pick cell style based on who the sender is
    var isUsersPost = 0
    if message.sender == userID {
        isUsersPost = 1
    }

    switch isUsersPost {
    case 1:
        let cell = chatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "rightChatCell") as! RightChatViewCell
    case 0:
        let cell = chatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chatCell") as! ChatViewCell
    default:
        let cell = chatTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chatCell") as! ChatViewCell
    }

    // fill in the cell properties with data - ca 200 lines of logic that is already optimised as much as reasonable
    cell.messageTextLabel = message.text 
    ... etc

    return cell   
    }
```

Here's my TableViewCell class (they are identical):

```
 import UIKit

 class RightChatViewCell: UITableViewCell {

var likeTask : (() -> Void)? = nil
var commentTask : (() -> Void)? = nil
var photoTask : (() -> Void)? = nil


@IBOutlet weak var messageBoxView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var messageTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nicknameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var profilePhotoView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var messageDateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var messageCommentLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var likeButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var messageLikesLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var messagePhotoView: UIImageView!

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    messagePhotoView.isHidden = true
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.none
    // Add photo Tap gesture recognizer
    messagePhotoView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(photoTapped)))
}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@objc func photoTapped() {
    print("Photo tapped")
    if let btnAction = self.photoTask
    {
        btnAction()
    }
}

@IBAction func likeTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Like tapped")
    if let btnAction = self.likeTask
    {
        btnAction()
    }
}

@IBAction func commentTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Comment tapped")
    if let btnAction = self.commentTask
    {
        btnAction()
    }
}

}
```

Comment: What you want to do with only work if your two cell classes have a common base class with all of the properties you are going to set after the `swift` or if your two cell classes both conform to a protocol that declares those common properties.

Comment: Wow! Thank you. That's a great Idea, I will try this out now. Would protocol make more sense in this case than a class? And if I go a protocol route how would I declare the cell variable?

Comment: It depends. If the only thing in common is some properties then a protocol is probably the better choice. If the two classes share common functionality, then a base class may be the better choice to avoid replicating code in both classes.

Comment: Ok, say I'm using the baseclass. How do I deal with the @IBOutlets etc that currently refer to different .xib file  for each subclass? So I can't connect them to base-class variables but have to do for each childclass separately, right? 99% of the variables and functionality is IB related.

Comment: Tried both options and problem is with the IBoutlets they don't work :(

Comment: Got a solution from another source. I just connected both XIB files and all their the outlets to same TableViewCell class and this solved the type conflict problem. But the big question still remains. How to define a untyped variable in a similar situation where this is not possible.

Answer (score -2):

If you declare the variables at the class level to null, 0 or ''; then instantiate them within your try and catch, though you will probably need to include an exception handler on the class as you will need to handle the issue if the instantiation isn't successful.

Have a look at this link on scope and variables
https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html

Comment: Tried, and got an error at declaration -- "nil' requires a contextual type" :) Back to square 1 :(